# How do you install a library in Delphi for Pascal?

Tags: delphi, shared-libraries, pascal

How do I go about installing a library such as [Velthuis.Console](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/console.html) to Delphi? I opened the .dpr file as suggested, but there is not an option to install as shown on other guides online. It compiles and works as intended, but how do I make it a shared library? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Add it to your project, either directly, or using the search path.

Comment: Well, @DavidHeffernan thank you for your suggestion. I guess that could be a solution, but what if I am planning on using it in many different projects? Would make it much easier if I could just type uses Math or whatever the name of the library is.

Comment: So put it in the search path. Do you use revision control?

Comment: Copy the three Velthuis.x.Pas files to a convenient folder on your system.  Add the path to that folder to the Source Path of your Delphi install, if it isn't already included.  Then you can simply add whichever one of the three you want to the Uses list of a new project.  You could set up a template of the project to the standard project templates Delphi makes available as the basis of new projects - details of the procedure to do this vary according to the Delphi version but is explained in the Online Help for it.

Comment: @MartynA thank you. When I add the units inside my project's folder, it works, but I did not manage to get it working outside. I tried adding the path under library, under source and still nothing. I think there must be some kind of central file which lists all the libraries installed or I do not know.

Comment: There is no magic to it, but which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @MartynA I am on 10.3 community edition which is the latest I believe. Not quite sure where exactly I am supposed to add the path. Is it under Tools>Options>Library or somewhere else? Other guides are suggesting to load the package and install it that way, but I guess it works differently based on version. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because it is boring and I do not actually know where to look. There are not many resources for Pascal in general.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you see anything about custom made libraries in this [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Frameworks_and_Libraries)?

Comment: You can't expect to make a feature up and then read the documentation. Only the features that exist are documented. Read about how to specify search paths. Can be done globally as well as per project. Or don't bother and continue making a fist of it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've downloaded Rudy's library as a .Zip file from the GitHub page linked by his article.

It will contain 3 flavours of his .Pas file which he put together to mimic the traditional Crt.Pas unit
that came with TurboPascal to provide easy-to-use basic screen- and keyboard-handling.  These are
                                                                                                 :
    Velthuis.AnsiConsole.Pas
    Velthuis.AutoConsole.Pas
    Velthuis.Console.Pas

The rest of this answer assumes you just want to use Velthuis.Console.Pas.  You want to be able to Use
this unit in future projects.

What your question boils down to is how do I tell Delphi where to look for the Console unit?

This is what I have done:

- I created a Rudy folder on my D: drive and unzipped the files to there.
- Next, if I didn't already have one, I would create a folder D:\D103Lib2.  The point of doing this
  is that Delphi's default config includes a Lib sub-folder which is where it looks for certain files it needs
  (like .Bpl and .Dcu files) and it will create you least grief in the long term if you don't start putting stuff
  in there.
- Next open ConsoleDemo.DProj in D:\Rudy and go to Project | Options in the IDE
- Right at the top of the pop-up. on the tab to the right of `Delphi Compiler`,
  click on the setting `Unit output directory` and set it to D:\D103Lib2, then dismiss
  the pop-up.  The point of doing that is that when you compile ConsoleDemo
  the compiler will in turn compile Velthuis.Console.Pas to produce the file and it will
  put that (but not the .Pas file) in D:\D103Lib2.
- Compile ConsoleDemo.  Compilation should succeed.
- Create a new Console App project and add `Velthuis.Console` to its Uses list.
- Try compiling the new project and the compiler will complain that it can't find
  `Velthuis.Console`
- Go to Project | Options | Delphi Compiler again and, in the tab on the right,
  in the `Search Path` **add** D:\D103Lib2.
- Try compiling the project again and this time compilation will succeed.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout: Indeed, he was an exceptional member of the Delphi community.  RIP.